# Error VBA "Saving a e-mail's attachment file in a folder"

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory

I'm trying to do a macro to save a attachment file from a e-mail in a folder.
But its showing me a Error '13' (Type mismatch). I'm looking for an answer but without success.

```
    Sub Arquivosanexos()

    Dim oltApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Namespace
    Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
    Dim MoveToFldr As MAPIFolder
    Dim olMi As MailItem
    Dim olAtt As Attachment
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim I As Long


    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set MoveToFldr = Fldr.Folders("TEST")
    MyPath = "C:\Folder1\Folder2\"

    For I = Fldr.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set olMi = Fldr.Items(I)
'Procura pelo nome do email
        If InStr(1, olMi.Subject, "Sample of e-mail's name") > 0 Then
            For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments
'Procura pelo nome do arquivo
             If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Sample of attachment's name") Then

             olAtt.SaveAsFile MyPath & ".xlsx"

             End If
            Next olAtt
            olMi.Save
            olMi.Move MoveToFldr
        End If
    Next I

    Set olAtt = Nothing
    Set olMi = Nothing
    Set Fldr = Nothing
    Set MoveToFldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify the line in the code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The line `Set olMi = Fldr.Items(I)` will cause a type mismatch if you have something other than a MailItem object, such as `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem`. Declare olMi as a generic Object.

Also keep in mind that looping through all items in a folder is a terrible idea - use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext`

UPDATE: search for PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC:

```
set restrItems = Fldr.Item.Restrict("SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0070001F"" LIKE '%Sample of e-mail''s name%' ")
```

Comment: Can you please give me a exemple about Items.Restrict?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it, give it try...

```
Option Explicit
Sub Arquivosanexos()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")

    FilePath = "C:\Temp\"

    For i = Inbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set Item = Inbox.Items(i)

        If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Sample of e-mails name") > 0 Then
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If Atmt.FileName = "Sample of attachments name.xlsx" Then
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile FilePath & Item.SenderName & ".xlsx"
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If

    Next i

    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Atmt = Nothing
End Sub
```